# Migrating Roaming Profiles from one drive to another

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, roaming-profile

As the title suggests, how can I migrate roaming profiles located in one drive (starting to fill up already) to another?

Current share is like this "SVR1\Shares\UserProfiles\%username%\
But of course, this is located in C:/Shares/UserProfiles/%username%/

What do I need to do? Do I simply copy/paste into the bigger(RAID1) drive and then repoint all the profile paths (using AD Users&Computers profile properties)?

What if I can point this to a different file server all together?

Best practices? tips? anything you guys can suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? I'm trying to hold off on doing this as I'm afraid I might break something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not as tough as it may seem.

1. You need to copy the profiles with their NTFS file system permissions. Robocopy is a good tool for that job. Try something like this:

   robocopy /mir /sec "source folder" "destination folder" /r:0 /np /log+:logfile.txt
2. Remove the file share from the old profile directory
3. Share the new profile directory under the same name as the old directory before.

You are done.

Additionally, here are some [guidelines on user profile design](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2009/01/user-profile-design-a-primer/).

Comment: I assume that it would also be alright if I used NTBACKUP? So it seems that moving Roaming Profiles folders, one has to be careful about retaining the permissions and the actual re-point of the "share".

Comment: Yes, NTBackup is another viable option. And yes, permissions and the share should stay the same.